# Combine reprlib and pprint in Python?

Tags: python, pprint

Can I have pretty printed data output as in `pprint.pprint` (new lines, indentation), but also shortened lists as in `reprlib.repr` at the same time?

An ugly hack seems to be `pprint(eval(reprlib.repr(data)))`, but is there a better way?

Comment: why don't you just crop the list yourself?  just reference `list[0:max]` and it will shorten it (to clarify:  even for lists of less than maximum length).  You can even be fancy and `append(...)` at the end.

Comment: @Scelesto `0` is the default slice start, so `list[:max]` works too.

Comment: @d33tah "repr is a Python built-in function that returns the canonical string representation of its input" The question isn't about it.

Comment: @Scelesto  That only works if the top level is the long list, not if the object *contains* long lists.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the way an object is printed by overriding the `__repr__()` method on its class.

Python will allow you to override the **repr** of any class, so use it with care.